# Align Items in swiftUI Stack Evenly

Tags: swiftui, alignment, swift5

How can the items in a swiftUI Stack be aligned evenly to fill up all the available space?
The first and last item should be straight at the beginning / end of the parent's Stack frame like so:

[image]

For those familiar with css, the desired behavior is equal to the css3 property `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;`.

Comment: Do you mean by ... that some items will be dropped if do not fit? Actually this is not the way how stacks work in SwiftUI - they fit to content, not vice-versa. You need custom layout to achieve that effect.

Comment: No not at all, I mean that the space is distriobuted dynamically. I tried to prevent answers suggesting hardcoded paddings that way. So its really just about alignment. I want the first item have like a leading padding of 0 and tha last on a trailing padding of zero. All items in-beetween should be placed in a way that tha space between them is equal.

Comment: Basically just add `Spacer()` between items in a `HStack`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach. Prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
struct ItemView: View {
    let value: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("Item\(value)")
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct JustifiedContainer<V: View>: View {
    let views: [V]
    
    init(_ views: V...) {
        self.views = views
    }

    init(_ views: [V]) {
        self.views = views
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(views.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                views[i]
                if views.count > 1 && i < views.count - 1 {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Demo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            JustifiedContainer(
                    ItemView(value: 1),
                    ItemView(value: 2),
                    ItemView(value: 3)
            )
            JustifiedContainer([
                    ItemView(value: 1),
                    ItemView(value: 2),
                    ItemView(value: 3),
                    ItemView(value: 4)
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing that it could be so simple. The View Wrapper is a elegant way -  one thought to add here, this won't work with a nested ForEach Block because the item-views are passed as parameter.